# Pagination does not work in coustom post archive wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made a custom post type archive page in theme (archive-cpt.php) and used new Wp_Query. When I'm trying to use `get_query_var("paged")` it opens `index.php` not `archive-cpt.php`.
What I should do?

`archive-cpt.php` source:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_args = array(
    "post_type" => HASHTIX_POST_TYPE,
    "post_status" => $post_status,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$process_posts = new WP_Query($post_args);
```

Comment: what do you mean it opens `index.php`? please share the content of `archive-cpt.php` as well.

Comment: opened homepage instead of archive page! url is like this `wordpress/hprocess/page/2`